# nginx returning error 502 when get not exist key on memcached

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, memcached, pecl

I use nginx 1.2.3(php-fpm) php 5.4.7 pecl memcached 2.1.0 memcached 1.4.15

If memcached service stops or gets a not found key, nginx returns 502 error and in **error_log** I see:

`2013/11/19 17:37:04 [error] 3972#0: *554345 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x , server: www.site.com, request: "GET /test/mk.php?get=var1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.site.com"`

**php-fpm.log** say:

```
[19-Nov-2013 17:58:32] WARNING: [pool www] child 4626 exited with code 127 after 18.892556 seconds from start
[19-Nov-2013 17:58:32] NOTICE: [pool www] child 4641 started
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The ngnix error means that www.site.com/test/mk.php?get=var1 doesn't reply to the http request.

Try to call www.site.com/test/mk.php?get=var1 directly, without nginx to see what is been actually returned.

Comment: i run my php file from cli and get:
php /srv/www/htdocs/hiclip/test/mk.php
php: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so: undefined symbol: memcached_last_rrno  
my pecl memcached version is 2.1 and libmemcached version 0.30.
i think update libmemcached solve problem.i test it later.

Answer (score 0):

i update libmemcached to 1.0.17 and i can't compile pecl memcached 2.1
https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/69
i install libmemcached 1.0.16 and install pecl memcached and my main problem solved.